# How to customize asl-google-signin-button?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-signin

I'm currently running an Angular16 project and I need to implement a Social Login button for Google. I did it with the help of *@abacritt/angularx-social-login@2.1.1*.

The issue on my side is that I need a custom button for this layout instead of the provided *asl-google-signin-button*, with my own style.

I've created a new button with a custom layout but I can't access the click() for the google button.

```
<app-button
  class="sign-up-button"
  (onclick)="loginWithGoogle()"
>
  <mat-icon class="icon-left" svgIcon="ic-google-colored"></mat-icon>
  Login with Google
</app-button>
<asl-google-signin-button
  #aslGoogleSigninButton
  id="asl-google-signin-button"
  type='icon'
  size='large'
  theme='filled_black'
  shape="rectangular"
  style="display:none;"
></asl-google-signin-button>
```

In my typescript, I added the following:

```
@ViewChild('aslGoogleSigninButton', {static: false}) aslGoogleSigninButton: ElementRef;

    loginWithGoogle(): void {
        this.aslGoogleSigninButton.nativeElement.click();
    }
```

With this code, I can't access the click() from the asl button, since the native element returns the following:

[image: asl-signin-button native element]

The click does work (with inspect) on the div that is pointed.. How can I make this work since it's inside an iframe?

Thank you for the help